# Add an image/button in Google Script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just added a script to a Form/Google Spreadsheet. It grabs the Response URL from the Form and pushes it into a column in the response spreadsheet. I would like to have the URL linked to a button(In html, I would of course anchor my image with the Edit Response URL, but now I am a little confuse, since I am not a super experienced script editor). How would that be possible to integrate it to my script?:

```
    function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1-Sxpvd9jktE-SVXV0_dfp018xwcIoa3aXMA_fdff9W8');
    //enter form ID here
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 5; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    resultUrls.push([urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

Comment: I didn't got exactly what's you're question, where is this HTML that you're talking about?

Comment: It is not there yet because I don't understand how to add it. Basically, all I want is that instead of showing the complete link in the spreadsheet, I would like to add the link to an image (like a button), or at least some text. Thanks :)

Comment: I though at first you wanted to show a modelessDialog or webApp because of the "HTML", as Zig stated there's no way to insert buttons in the sheet like that, only show an HTML that has clicable buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to programatically add buttons or images to spreadsheets.
what you can do is add the url in those cells as a fomula =hyperlink("url",yoururl) so it looks prettier.